# Background and footline for beamerposter header

Tags: beamer, header-footer, beamerposter

How can I add a grey background and black footline to this beamer header?

EDIT: Here's a compiling MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[size = custom, height = 110, width = 81]{beamerposter}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{175,1,1}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{\linewidth}
    \vskip2cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{darkred}\VERYHuge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[1.5ex]}
    \vskip2cm
  \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
}
\title{A Rhapsody in Foo}
\begin{document}
  Foo.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @samcarter Done

Answer (score 1):

The background can be added by a `beamercolorbox` and the footline by a `rule`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[size = custom, height = 110, width = 81]{beamerposter}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{175,1,1}
\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=black,bg=gray!30}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \leavevmode
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}%
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{\linewidth}
            \vskip2cm
            \centering
            \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{darkred}\VERYHuge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[1.5ex]}
            \vskip2cm
        \end{column}
        \vspace{1cm}
    \end{columns}
    \rule{\paperwidth}{10pt}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\title{A Rhapsody in Foo}
\begin{document}
    Foo.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ya, but can the footline be any thinner?

Comment: @RenéG Of course! Simply adjust the 20pt according to your needs

Comment: Also, it didn't work for me when I put in my custom beamerposter size

Comment: @RenéG Can you add your custom beamerposter size to your MWE?

Comment: @RenéG see the updated answer with your custom size.